# Dynamics CRM Get Info For Customer

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm working on a ASP.NET (C#) site that pulls most of its data from Dynamics CRM over SOAP using Microsoft's CrmService SDK.

I'm at the point where a query has returned an entity with a property of the type Customer. I need to get the name string of that customer record, but cannot figure out how to do so.

By doing a little guess work I figured out that what I have is GUID for the customer. How can I use this GUID to get the customer's name as a string?

Relevant Links:

[CrmService Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa613627(v=MSDN.10).aspx)
[Customer Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa613735.aspx)
[Customer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa613716.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly to get the name of the Customer you should be able to do:

```
yourEntity.Customer.name;
```

The following code would give you the GUID:

```
yourEntity.Customer.Value;
```

Comment: Wow, if I only knew it was that simple :-)